# Next.jsでfirebase.storage()エラー firebase.storage is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

Reactでfirebase.storage()を使うことはできたのですが(firebase7.20.0), Next.jsで同じコードを書いたのにfirebase.storage is not a function のエラーメッセージが出てしまいます.

何が原因なのでしょうか.

firebase 7.23.0

```
import firebase from "firebase";

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
 // config
};

const firebaseApp = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebaseApp.storage()

export { auth, provider, storage };

export default db;
```

Answer (score 0):

import "firebase/storage";
こちらがないからだと思います。